# Dual top navigation bar with twitter bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I noticed some websites having a dual navbar at the top. The first is for indicating user session status (login / logout / settings etc) and the lower one is for actual site functionality. I have attached a screenshot - can anyone point me to some code example on how I can replicate the same?

Thanks
[image]

Comment: See this link http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar-default

Comment: @Jake745 the default bootstrap examples show how to get a single nav bar like the one we have on this website. However, there is no example for a dual nav-bar like I have shown in the screenshot. Is there a specific area in that link that I am missing out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just try this from bootstrap:

```
<div class="navbar">
  <div class="navbar-inner">
    <div class="container">

      <!-- .btn-navbar is used as the toggle for collapsed navbar content -->
      <a class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </a>

      <!-- Be sure to leave the brand out there if you want it shown -->
      <a class="brand" href="#">Project name</a>

      <!-- Everything you want hidden at 940px or less, place within here -->
      <div class="nav-collapse collapse">
        <!-- .nav, .navbar-search, .navbar-form, etc -->
      </div>

     </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: dear if u r using one from bootstrap then write down the same code after that nd give it margin from upper navbar.u can use it twice.

Comment: @ChicagoSky: happy to help u...if it works for u please accept the answer so it can b helpful to others.